# How can i access the value of particular field in Schema

Tags: apex, leads

Here in `fld` i have all fields of Lead Object and now i want to create a new Account and Name of the Account will be Lead's Name

```
public void show()
    {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult a_desc = Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe(); 
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> a_fields = a_desc.fields.getMap();
        List<String> str = new List<String>();
        for(Schema.sObjectField fld:a_fields.values()){
            str.add(','+fld);
            //system.debug(fld);
        }
        String query = 'SELECT id'+str+' FROM Lead)';
        List<Lead> leadList = database.query(query);

        for(Lead sObjLead : leadList){
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.name = sObjLead.name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not have a `Lead` instance here - just information about the `Lead` object. Where is the data you want to use?

Comment: I've made some changes in Code, can you please check now. Weather this is correct way or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void show()
    {
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult a_desc = Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe(); 
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> a_fields = a_desc.fields.getMap();
        String str = '';
        for(Schema.sObjectField fld : a_fields.values()){
            str += ','+fld.getDescribe().getName();
        }
        String query = 'SELECT '+str.removeStart(',')+' FROM Lead';
        system.debug('query => '+query);
        List<Lead> leadList = database.query(query);

        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(Lead sObjLead : leadList){
            accList.add(new Account(Name=sObjLead.name));
        }
        system.debug(accList);
        // insert accList;
    }
```

This should work.

1. fld is sObjectField, so you need to extract API name from its describe result.
2. Change str to str (not list)
3. Add new account to account like in loop

Comment: Thank You @salesforcesas for Explaining Point No.1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult a_desc = Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe(); 
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> a_fields = a_desc.fields.getMap();
        List<String> strList = new List<String>();
        for(Schema.SObjectField field : a_fields.values()){
            strList.add(field.getDescribe().getName());
            //system.debug(fld);
        }
        String query = 'SELECT Id, ' + String.join(strList, ', ') + ' FROM Lead';
```